# NSTextInputClientで日本語入力時に漢字変換候補選択ウインドウの向き（縦横）を変える

Tags: objective-c, 日本語

NSTextViewを使わずに、NSTextInputClientを使って日本語入力を行うカスタムビューを作成しています。日本語漢字変換を行う際に漢字変換候補選択ウインドウが表示されますが、文面が横書きでも縦書きでも、常に横書き用の「横向きの候補選択ウインドウ」が表示されてしまい、「縦向きの候補選択ウインドウ」へ切り替える方法がわかりません。
どなたか「候補選択ウインドウの向き」を縦横切り替える方法をご教示下さい。
（NSTextViewや付属アプリのTextEditでは文面の向きに応じて、候補選択ウインドウの向きも変えられるようです）

[image: レイアウトが横向きの候補選択ウインドウ]　　→　[image: レイアウトが縦向きの候補選択ウインドウ]

Answer (score 1):

`NSTextInputClient` のプロトコルメソッド `- (BOOL)drawsVerticallyForCharacterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)charIndex`[1] を使うと変換候補のメニュの縦書き、横書きを指定することができます。

[1] [- drawsVerticallyForCharacterAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextInputClient_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextInputClient/drawsVerticallyForCharacterAtIndex:)